# Flexdashboard - Scroll multiple graphs written under a single R chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a flexdashboard with several tabs. One of them needs to include multiple graphs (~50). I produce the graphs under one single chunk within a loop (because numbers of graphs varies each time). What I get in the output is showing only some graphs without being able to scroll to see the rest of them. Scroll is totally deactivated but graphs are printed.

So far I've tried and didn't work to:

- change the vertical_layout = scroll
- adjust the row-height but graphs got shrunk (not readable)
- download latest version of flexdashboard
- include some CSS style (overflow-x: scrollbar;)
- run the same in simple rmakrdown and works fine
- when you put each graph in different chunk, scroll works properly but it doesn't solve my problem

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: This function is one work-around.
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/